# How to make this Dragon Curve?

Tags: graphics, fractals

[image]

I made it by another software, and met some problems to change it into MMA code.

```
f[x_] := Graphics[
 Line[AnglePath[{90 °, -90 °}[[
  1 + Nest[Join[#, {0}, Reverse[1 - #]] &, {0}, x]]]]]];
f /@ Range[5]
```

The effect is weird.

It has two affine rules

$(x,y)\to(0.5x-0.5y,0.5x+0.5y)$ and $(x,y)\to(-0.5x-0.5y+1,0.5x-0.5y)$

for example:

```
g[{x_, y_}] := Block[
{}, Return[{{0.5 x - 0.5 y, 0.5 x + 0.5 y}, {-0.5 x - 0.5 y + 1, 
 0.5 x - 0.5 y}}]
]
h[x_] := Flatten[g /@ x] // Partition[#, 2] &
NestList[h, {{0, 0}}, 13] // ListPlot
```

gives [image]

So,I know how to plot still picture, But I have no idea about let it animate.

Comment: Add a definition of the curve and your code attempts.

Comment: the origin link about this gif: https://www.netpad.net.cn/resource_web/course/#/36439 click the "animate" to see the animation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think OP may want animation with transition effects. Compare these two effects:

[image]

Then translation

[image]

```
Clear["`*"]
cf = Compile[{{M, _Real, 2}, t},
   With[{A = M[[1]], B = M[[2]]}, 
    With[{P = (A + B + t Cross[B - A])/2}, {{A, P}, {B, P}}]], RuntimeAttributes -> Listable
   ];

f[n_] := Flatten[Nest[cf[#, 1] &, {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}}, Floor@n], Floor@n];
g[n_] := Flatten[cf[f[n], FractionalPart[n]], 1];

Manipulate[Graphics[{Line[f[n]]}, PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 1.2}, {-0.4, 0.7}}], {n, 0, 12}]
Manipulate[Graphics[{Line[g[n]]}, PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 1.2}, {-0.4, 0.7}}], {n, 0, 12}]

Manipulate[
 With[{i = Floor[n], TF = TranslationTransform},
  Graphics[{
    Table[Line[TF[{2 j, 0}]@f[j]], {j, 0, n}],
    Line@If[n - i < 0.5, TF[{4 n - 2 i, 0}]@f[n], TF[{2 i + 2, 0}]@g[2 n - i - 1]]
    }, ImageSize -> 670, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 13.2}, {-0.5, 0.8}}]],
 {n, 0, 6}]
```

Comment: The top right one is super cool looking.

Comment: @evanb Thank you.

Comment: @evanb actually I have made one before:) https://www.netpad.net.cn/resource_web/course/#/30921

Answer (score 25):

[image]

A simple way to make Dragon Curve is using `AnglePath`. Define a function that generates points for the Dragon curve:

```
dragonPTS[k_]:=AnglePath[{Pi/2,-Pi/2}[[1+Nest[Join[#,{0},Reverse[1-#]]&,{0},k]]]]
```

`k` is an integer number of iterations. Try it out:

```
Graphics[Line[dragonPTS[10]]]
```

[image]

Now generate a list of the transitions:

```
Table[Graphics[Line[dragonPTS[k]]], {k, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

or animate:

```
Manipulate[Table[Graphics[Line[dragonPTS[k]]], {k, 1, n, 1}], {n, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

To make it a bit cleaner - as in the top animation image - you can try:

```
Manipulate[
    Row[Table[Graphics[Line[dragonPTS[k]],ImageSize->100{1,1}],{k,1,n,1}]],
{n,1,10,1},Paneled->False,AppearanceElements->None]
```

Also see numerous interactive apps at Demonstrations Project:

https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=Dragon

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar code made by [Apple](https://github.com/ChenMinQi/chenminqi.github.io/tree/master/Koch%E6%9B%B2%E7%BA%BF%E7%9A%84%E5%8A%A8%E6%80%81%E5%8C%96), just for reference.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
rotate[p4_, p2_] := Evaluate[Simplify@RotationTransform[1. Pi/3, p2][p4]];
generate[p1_, p5_] := Module[{p2, p3, p4},
    p2 = (p5 - p1)/3 + p1;
    p4 = 2 (p5 - p1)/3 + p1;
    p3 = rotate[p4, p2];
    {p1, p2, p3, p4}];

data[0]=N@{{ 0, 0}, {1, 0}};
data[n_] := data[n] = Flatten[{generate @@@ Partition[data[n - 1], 2, 1], {{{ 1, 0}}}}, 2];

move[{p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_, p5_}, t_] := {{p1, p2, (1 - t) p4 + t p3}, {(1 - t) p2 + t p3, p4, p5}};
AllMove[data_, t_] := move[#, t] & /@ Partition[data, 5, 4];
newdata[t_] := Flatten[AllMove[data[Quotient[t + 1, 1]], Mod[t, 1]], 1];

Manipulate[ListLinePlot[newdata[t], PlotRange -> {{ 0, 1}, {-0.02, 0.3}}, AspectRatio -> 0.32, 
        Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.353, 0.741, 0.913], ImageSize -> {500, 200}],
    {t, 0, 4, 0.03},SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: I have made this before:) https://www.netpad.net.cn/resource_web/course/#/30919